# Block host from auto ripping my content

Tags: apache, centos, lamp

Via google analytics I noticed that there is website which is scrapping my content automatically.. His content 100% matches mine. is there any way I could block that website host from accesing my server at all? Any solutions what I could do about this?
Im running LAMP web host on CentOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the IP address of the scraping host is static, you can use `.htaccess` to block this IP, like:

```
order allow,deny
deny from 111.111.111.111
allow from all
```

If the IP address is variable, but the user agent is constant, you can use agent blocking:

```
BrowserMatchNoCase SpammerRobot bad_bot
BrowserMatchNoCase SecurityHoleRobot bad_bot
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from env=bad_bot
```